# Optimizing 2x 1.8GB tables takes 50 minutes

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, optimization, mysql-8.0

I am running `MySQL 8.0.30` on `Rocky Linux 9`, cpu is 12 threads AMD Ryzen, 128 GB ram, a decent NVME SSD. And ... I struggle with relatively large databases, currently around 200GB in total, around 20 tables, 2-3 tables are over 50GB each.

I wanted to `optimize` 2 tables mostly to then compare them with different column data types, to see which one would take more space, which one would run search queries faster, etc. Otherwise I assume this is a costly operation that might not be needed.

Now I stopped all processes and queries and ran `OPTIMIZE table` on 2 smaller tables that are 1.8 GB each, 1 million records in each table.

**It took 50 minutes to complete and I don't udnerstand why.**

```
time 2949
state: copy to tmp table
info: OPTIMIZE TABLE `url_meta_TEST_1`, `url_meta_TEST_2`
```

While this query was running, I ran `iotop` command and it shown that it was **constantly writing to SSD with around 300MB/s**

The server had 52GB memory "available" from 128GB:

```
free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           124Gi        72Gi       3.9Gi        84Mi        49Gi        52Gi
```

/etc/my.cnf

```
skip-log-bin
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64G
```

Maybe relevant ... the folder `/var/lib/mysql/db_name` is 354GB in total (with huge `fts_*_index_x.ibd` files), even thou PhpMyAdmin shows all table's total as 182GB, for the size of the db files there I might need to open another question.

- **Why does it take so much to optimize ?**
- **Does anything look wrong with the indexes, column types, etc ?**
- **Can this 50 minutes time be normal in case data was fragmented ?**

**EDIT:** I ran the exact same query again, after the 2 tables were already optimized, it takes same amount of time, and again it constantly writes to disk 350-450MB/s.

[image]

**Edit:** including more date:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE url_meta_TEST_1;

url_meta_TEST_1 | CREATE TABLE `url_meta_TEST_1` (
  `url_hash` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `url_sharding` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `url_title` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `url_keywords` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_paragraphs` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `url_total_links_in` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'max SMALLINT is 65535',
  `url_meta_date` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url_misc` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `url_hash` (`url_hash`),
  KEY `url_total_links_in` (`url_total_links_in`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `url_sharding` (`url_sharding`),
  KEY `url_misc` (`url_misc`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `url_meta_index` (`url_title`,`url_description`,`url_keywords`,`url_paragraphs`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%size';
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                                            | Value                |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size                                        | 32768                |
| binlog_row_event_max_size                                | 8192                 |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                                   | 32768                |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size               | 25000                |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                                  | 8388608              |
| connection_memory_chunk_size                             | 8912                 |
| delayed_queue_size                                       | 1000                 |
| histogram_generation_max_mem_size                        | 20000000             |
| host_cache_size                                          | 279                  |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                            | 134217728            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                                  | 68719476736          |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size                            | 25                   |
| innodb_ddl_buffer_size                                   | 1048576              |
| innodb_doublewrite_batch_size                            | 0                    |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                                     | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                                 | 84                   |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                                 | 3                    |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                               | 640000000            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                                   | 16777216             |
| innodb_log_file_size                                     | 50331648             |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size                              | 8192                 |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                                 | 1073741824           |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size                         | 134217728            |
| innodb_page_size                                         | 16384                |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                                  | 300                  |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                                  | 1048576              |
| innodb_sync_array_size                                   | 1                    |
| join_buffer_size                                         | 262144               |
| key_buffer_size                                          | 8388608              |
| key_cache_block_size                                     | 1024                 |
| large_page_size                                          | 0                    |
| max_binlog_cache_size                                    | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                                          | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                               | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_heap_table_size                                      | 16777216             |
| max_join_size                                            | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_relay_log_size                                       | 0                    |
| myisam_data_pointer_size                                 | 6                    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size                                | 9223372036853727232  |
| myisam_mmap_size                                         | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                                  | 8388608              |
| ngram_token_size                                         | 2                    |
| optimizer_trace_max_mem_size                             | 1048576              |
| parser_max_mem_size                                      | 18446744073709551615 |
| performance_schema_accounts_size                         | -1                   |
| performance_schema_digests_size                          | 10000                |
| performance_schema_error_size                            | 5153                 |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size       | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_size            | 10                   |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size   | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_size        | 10                   |
| performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size      | 10                   |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size        | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size             | 10                   |
| performance_schema_hosts_size                            | -1                   |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size            | 512                  |
| performance_schema_setup_actors_size                     | -1                   |
| performance_schema_setup_objects_size                    | -1                   |
| performance_schema_users_size                            | -1                   |
| preload_buffer_size                                      | 32768                |
| profiling_history_size                                   | 15                   |
| query_alloc_block_size                                   | 8192                 |
| query_prealloc_size                                      | 8192                 |
| range_alloc_block_size                                   | 4096                 |
| range_optimizer_max_mem_size                             | 8388608              |
| read_buffer_size                                         | 131072               |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                                     | 262144               |
| rpl_read_size                                            | 8192                 |
| select_into_buffer_size                                  | 131072               |
| sort_buffer_size                                         | 262144               |
| thread_cache_size                                        | 9                    |
| tmp_table_size                                           | 16777216             |
| transaction_alloc_block_size                             | 8192                 |
| transaction_prealloc_size                                | 4096                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
75 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%sort%';
+-------------------+---------+
| Variable_name     | Value   |
+-------------------+---------+
| Sort_merge_passes | 6964    |
| Sort_range        | 0       |
| Sort_rows         | 5129121 |
| Sort_scan         | 12573   |
+-------------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Uptime        | 78313 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'url_meta_TEST%';
+-----------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name            | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-----------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| url_meta_TEST_1 | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 818729 |           2175 |  1781530624 |               0 |    108331008 |   4194304 |           NULL | 2022-12-22 01:03:20 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| url_meta_TEST_2 | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 872950 |           2040 |  1781530624 |               0 |    108331008 |   4194304 |           NULL | 2022-12-22 01:03:20 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-----------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft%';
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value          |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax               | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len                 | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len                 | 4              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit        | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file                | (built-in)     |
| innodb_ft_aux_table             |                |
| innodb_ft_cache_size            | 8000000        |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print     | OFF            |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword       | ON             |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size        | 84             |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size        | 3              |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize     | 2000           |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    | 2000000000     |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table |                |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree       | 2              |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size      | 640000000      |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   |                |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT:** adding a sample query that would be nice to run faster:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  url_meta_cache
    WHERE  url_hash IN ('1a0b004256a5c7fd','1fcc4489f4195c95')
      AND  match(url_title, url_description, url_keywords, url_paragraphs)
           against('contact' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    LIMIT  2000;
```

It times out in PhpMyAdmin, over 15-20 seconds to run.
The `url_hash` is indexed, if I just run first part (before match against) it runs instantly. I was expecting it to run second query only inside rows that matched in first part.
Is it because I didn't set `url_hash` as `PRMARY` index ?!

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM url_meta_cache WHERE url_hash IN ('1a0b004256a5c7fd','1fcc4489f4195c95') AND match(url_title, url_description, url_keywords, url_paragraphs) against('contact' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type     | possible_keys           | key            | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | url_meta_cache | NULL       | fulltext | url_hash,url_meta_index | url_meta_index | 0       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.50 sec)


{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "0.49"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "url_meta_cache",
      "access_type": "fulltext",
      "possible_keys": [
        "url_hash",
        "url_meta_index"
      ],
      "key": "url_meta_index",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "url_title"
      ],
      "key_length": "0",
      "ref": [
        "const"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "ft_hints": "no_ranking",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "0.39",
        "eval_cost": "0.10",
        "prefix_cost": "0.49",
        "data_read_per_join": "3K"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "url_hash",
        "url_sharding",
        "url",
        "url_title",
        "url_description",
        "url_keywords",
        "url_paragraphs",
        "url_total_links_in",
        "url_meta_date",
        "url_misc"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`crawlson`.`url_meta_cache`.`url_hash` in ('1a0b004256a5c7fd','1fcc4489f4195c95')) and (match `crawlson`.`url_meta_cache`.`url_title`,`crawlson`.`url_meta_cache`.`url_description`,`crawlson`.`url_meta_cache`.`url_keywords`,`crawlson`.`url_meta_cache`.`url_paragraphs` against ('contact' in boolean mode)))"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` on the 'sample query'.

Comment: I added the `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`, I ran this on server #2 (of 4) where I know the two url hashes exists in table. It just returns no results if I also do the text bolean search. Or 2 results if I just look for the hashes (first part).

Comment: I see `EXAPLAIN` says `POSSIBLE KEYS: url_hash,url_meta_index; KEY: url_meta_index`, does it use the second index (which is way larger) and not narrow rows by `url_hash` first ?

Comment: It knows how to do FULLTEXT against the entire table; it does not know how to check 2 rows for text.  The FT index is an "inverted" index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64G` -- Change to 100G.

To `OPTIMIZE` 50GB table, the table will be completely copied over.  This may require reading 50GB into the buffer_pool and writing upwards of 50GB to disk.  Both the read and write may be mostly "streamed".  But then there are the indexes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so that we can discuss other things.  If there are lots of big indexes, that could be 10s of GB more to build in the buffer_pool and/or send through the disk.

The time taken for Optimize does not depend much on fragmentation; but rather on other factors.

Since InnoDB stores the *data* in `PRIMARY KEY` order, the rows are not scattered, but they *may* have gaps -- that is, 16KB blocks that are less than full.

Let's also see the queries you are hoping to optimize; we may be able to make more suggestions.

In general, I advise against ever using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB tables.  Often there is no shrinkage in size, nor any improvement in the performance of subsequent queries.

True, if you need to read the entire table to do the search, then table size is important.  I would hope that you have investigated `INDEXes`, `FULLTEXT`, and `SPATIAL`.

Let's see

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%size';
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%sort%';
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'url_meta_TEST%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft%';
```

Contrary to what I see on one of your screenshots,...
`SMALLINT` defaults to `SIGNED`, with a max of 32767.
`SMALLINT UNSIGNED` mas a mas of 65525.

It looks like 3 of the indexes are useless (Cardinality = 1).

How is the 'hash' calculated?  It is probably very random, meaning that building that index will involve jumping around a lot.

"writes to disk 350-450MB/s" --> that's how fast the SSD runs.  The only way to speed up writes is to *avoid* writes.  (Avoid `OPTIMIZE` and have better `INDEXes`.)

**sort_buffer_size** Seems like a likely thing to change.  Suggest 1G (instead of 256M).  I expect `Sort_merge_passes` to decrease significantly.  That metric is sometimes an indicator of lots of I/O.  (The connection is complicated.)  It is a "counter", so check the value before and after an Optimize.

**Forcing filtering order**

Since the Optimizer blindly assumes that `MATCH` is both faster and easier, it does that first.  However, your case would prefer the `IN` to be done first.

If you *know* that the `IN` should be done first, then this may be the only way to speed it up.  Currently:

```
WHERE  url_hash IN ('1a0b004256a5c7fd','1fcc4489f4195c95')
  AND  match(url_title, url_description, url_keywords, url_paragraphs)
       against('contact' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Proposed:

```
WHERE  url_hash IN ('1a0b004256a5c7fd','1fcc4489f4195c95')
  AND  ( url_title LIKE '%contact%' )
         OR url_title       LIKE '%contact%'
         OR url_description LIKE '%contact%'
         OR url_keywords    LIKE '%contact%'
         OR url_paragraphs  LIKE '%contact%' )
```

That will very rapidly fetch the two rows, then slowly do the LIKEs.  (Since only 2 rows are involved, the speed of the LIKEs is not an issue.)

Caveat:  This does not do things that MATCH does such as respecting word boundaries.

Comment: I included `SHOW CREATE TABLE url_meta_TEST_1;` in the question details.

Comment: Added the variables too ...

Comment: The 2 indexes that have `cardinality = 1` are because I only copied a small portion of a larger table. The 'hash' is a `md5()` of full url string, and I trunated it to 16 chars, because there are low chanes for conflicts and would not be a huge problem. I use that to shard data across multiple servers.

Comment: And the `url_sharding (2)` is url_hash truncated to first 1-2 chars, so if I add servers, I can select/move data that has `url_sharding=x` or `url_sharding=xy`

Comment: Added a sample query at the end of the question.

Comment: @adrianTNT - That new SELECT puzzles me.  Is url_hash UNIQUE in `url_meta_cache`?  If so the MATCH and LIMIT are of dubious use since there cannot be more than two rows.

Comment: I suggest picking the sharding chars from a different spot in the MD5.  (This gives you a tiny bit of extra protection against an unlikely dup.)

Comment: @adrianTNT - And see my new comment on `sort_buffer_size`

Comment: The `url_hash` is unique, yes, the `LIMIT 2000` is there because it sometimes looks for over 2000 hashes and it should stop if it found 2000. The `MATCH AGAINST ...` is to also look for a text in URL title, description, etc.

Comment: The problem is that the Optimizer will assume that MATCH is faster than anything else and do that first -- even if it returns thousands of rows.  After that it filters down to the two.  If that is the typical query, I'll provide some clumsy suggestions.

Comment: I can manually split that particular query in PHP code, to just find the few `url_hash`'es first, and then look for text in the few rows. Unless there is a better solution to tell MySQL the order in which to look ?

Comment: I added the equivalent in SQL.  Not pretty.

Comment: The proposed query is simple to understand, but I think it would not allow me to add `-word` negative matches. What if I convert all the 4 columns to normal indexes (not full text), would that perform worse ? And more importantly, can I still do bolean search (`+word -word`) if is not a full text index ? Thank you.

Comment: @adrianTNT - Even uglier: `AND (x1 NOT LIKE '%y%` AND x2 NOT LIKE '%y%' ).  A normal INDEX is useles for `LIKE` with _leading_ wildcard; don't add normal index.

Comment: So `MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN` only works with full text indexes ? (I wasn't sure about this).

Comment: Sorry, one more question, hopefully the last: the reason my sample query didn't search text just in the two matched `url_hash` records, is that because full text is stored all in one place and any query goes trough all the index data always ? Did I get that right ?

Comment: @adrianTNT -  Yes, `MATCH` works only with `FULLTEXT`.  And `LIKE` and `RLIKE` do not work with `FULLTEXT`, just `INDEX`, UNIQUE`, and `PRIMARY KEY`....

Comment: @adrianTNT - re "one more" -- Yes, mostly.  The innards of `FULLTEXT` is such that it has a list of the rows that contain `contact` (etc).  It's called an "inverted index".  So it does not "go through _all_ the index always".  The problem comes in that there is not 'direct' connection between the inverted index and the B+Tree used for that `IN`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I am learning a lot from these answers / comments.

Comment: More MySQL tips to learn here:  mysql.rjweb.org

Comment: I opened a similar question, maybe you can take a look, but no pressure :) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321433/very-slow-drop-index-add-primary-key-index