# Very slow DROP INDEX, ADD PRIMARY KEY index

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, index, optimization

This is probably related to [another question I had](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321292/optimizing-2x-1-8gb-tables-takes-50-minutes/321295), but not sure.

So my table `url_meta` is 25 GB including data and indexes, 70 million records.

```
Data        18.3 GiB
Index       7.3 GiB
Overhead    5.0 MiB
Effective   25.5 GiB
Total       25.5 GiB
```

I wanted to change a index column `url_hash` to be primary, so I ran this query:

```
ALTER TABLE url_meta DROP INDEX url_hash, ADD PRIMARY KEY (url_hash) USING BTREE
```

And it runs for 7 hours and counting, the ssd ls almost out of space and I assume query will fail.

To me **it seems that it takes way to long to process 25GB**

Server has 128 GB ram, 12 threads Ryzen CPU, nvme ssd.

Only options in /etc/my.cnf:

```
skip-log-bin

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G

sort_buffer_size = 1G
```

PhpMyAdmin says:

> Many temporary tables are being written to disk instead of being kept in memory.
> Recommendation:
> Increasing max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size might help

So these are the two variables:

```
tmp_table_size      16,​777,​216
max_heap_table_size 16,​777,​216
```

- Are the two above variables related to my slow `ALTER TABLE` queries?
- If yes, what values should these two be in my situation ?
- If not these 2, what variables should I tune to make this alter tables faster ?
- What other variables should I check / edit in order to use more memory and less of the SSD ?
- Table contains a full text index that I assume it got really big, is that wahat causes my problems ?

This is the table fomat:

```
CREATE TABLE `url_meta` (
  `url_hash` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `url_sharding` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `url_title` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `url_keywords` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_paragraphs` mediumtext,
  `url_total_links_in` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'max SMALLINT is 65535',
  `url_meta_date` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url_misc` tinyint DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


-- Indexes

ALTER TABLE `url_meta`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `url_hash` (`url_hash`),
  ADD KEY `url_total_links_in` (`url_total_links_in`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `url_sharding` (`url_sharding`),
  ADD KEY `url_misc` (`url_misc`);
ALTER TABLE `url_meta` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `url_meta_index` (`url_title`,`url_description`,`url_keywords`,`url_paragraphs`);
COMMIT;
```

My large files in `/var/lib/mysql/db_name`

```
ls -lhaS /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts*
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  81G Dec 24 18:24 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000961_0000000000000a57_index_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  40G Dec 25 23:58 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000a3d_0000000000000bae_index_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  13G Dec 23 23:06 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000961_0000000000000a57_index_6.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.3G Dec 25 04:15 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000a31_0000000000000b9b_index_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 6.5G Dec 22 04:30 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_00000000000009ec_0000000000000b2f_index_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 6.5G Dec 23 04:37 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000a20_0000000000000b7d_index_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 6.4G Dec 25 23:58 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000a3d_0000000000000bae_index_6.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Dec 25 04:15 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_0000000000000a31_0000000000000b9b_index_6.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 844M Dec 22 04:30 /var/lib/mysql/my_db/fts_00000000000009ec_0000000000000b2f_index_6.ibd
# more smaller ones ...
```

My current memory usage during this long query, not sure, but maybe it has room to use more memory and write less to disk ?
It shows it is swapping too, no ? I assume this is bad.

```
free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           124Gi        91Gi       804Mi        60Mi        33Gi        33Gi
Swap:           31Gi        22Gi       8.3Gi
```

Comment: Primary key in InnoDB is clustered always - so your ALTER TABLE causes complete table rewriting. This cannot be fast.

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-primary-key-operations says:

> Restructuring the clustered index always requires copying of table data.

You can still use INPLACE (with some exceptions, see the manual I linked to), but this doesn't change the requirement to copy the data to a new tablespace, which requires a lot more storage space. In fact, INPLACE is a misleading name for that feature. It just means you can continue to do DML statements against the table while it is rebuilding (changes are queued up, which uses even more disk space). For more on this, read https://klouddb.io/understanding-how-online-ddl-inplace-works-in-mysql/

The time it takes to run this alter is not only related to the size of the table. It could take longer if the server is heavily loaded with other work.

Besides that, something else doesn't add up. The FTS files you show total over 160GB. This seems overly large because you said your entire table is only 25GB. I know that fulltext indexes can be bulky, but I expect it to be roughly 1.5x the size of the text data. Yours is more than 6x.

There should be a file `/var/lib/mysql/my_db/url_meta.ibd` that is the actual tablespace. How large is that file?

If you are running out of disk space, you might need to drop the fulltext index while you are performing the ALTER TABLE. You can rebuild the fulltext index after it's done.

You should always make sure you have enough disk space. If you are running out of space so that you can't perform a table-copy, you're already past the point when you either need to increase disk space, or else move some data to another server.

Comment: The `url_meta.ibd` is around same size as table size in PhpMyAdmin, around `24GB`, but the `80GB fts_*_index_1.ibd` file was associated with text index of this table, it went away after moving data to another table and deleted this one, but I assume fts file will grow again. I added some details on Rick-James's answer. As I understand, the FTS files will grow / move / regroup based on executed searches too ? If so, I don't think FTS is usable for me anymore.

Comment: FTS files are the fulltext index. They grow in proportion to the number of rows they index, and the length of the text. They do not grow simply from executing searches.

Comment: The builtin fulltext indexing of MySQL is pretty limited. If you have another option, i.e. another technology product that is a special-purpose text indexing product, that's usually better for performance and for fulltext features. But it's your responsibility to manage the copy of text data in the fulltext index, and keep it in sync with the data you store in MySQL.

Comment: I seen your SlideShare about full text search in `myisam, innodb, apache solr, sphinx search`, that was since 2009, is it still relevant, should I give Sphinx Search a go ? I need it for a search engine, to lookup text in `title, description, keywords, paragraphs`. Thank you.

Comment: I'd take a look at ElasticSearch. But you do need to try out several technologies to evaluate them and see if they are appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the lengthy `ALTER`, but I have something to tell you.  The `ALTER` was unnecessary.  The table already had `url_hash` as the PK.  Every InnoDB table has a PK, from this list:

1. An explicit `PRIMARY KEY` (what you were striving for);
2. The first `UNIQUE` key with only `NOT NULL` columns (what you had);
3. A hidden 6-byte number.

See `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM` url_meta;` and notice "PRI" in the "Key" column.

A side question... Is the hash a hex value?  That could be shrunk via `UNHEX` to `BINARY(8)`, which would shrink the table some.

Your buffer_pool size seems plenty generous.  The "free -h" is inconclusive.  The two "_table_size" setting are, I think, irrelevant.

**More**

As I understand it, any change the the `PRIMARY KEY` (such as `DROP` or `ADD`) will only be done via `ALGORITHM=COPY`.  Also, I believe that `ALTER` will use the most efficient algorithm, but based on a simple analysis of what you request.

What MySQL version?  The recent versions will do `DROP INDEX` 'instantly', and do `ADD INDEX` apparently instantly.  Actually the work is done in the background, to be usable sometime later.  (Check for exceptions.)  Adding an index later will _probably scan the entire table, write to a disk file, sort that file, put the index in place, and finally make it "visible".  This should have an effect equivalent to `OPTIMIZE` in that the B+Tree for that index will be without gaps.  (I don't see `DROP` + `ADD` on the same index being being worth doing.)

Comment: The hash is a `MD5` of the full url text (truncated to 16 chars), so I can identify unique urls by shorter data, I also use that with memcached, to check if url exists or cache total links pointing to that 16 chars `url_hash`.

Comment: Now even if you said `ALTER TABLE` was not needed, I need to complete it because it completed on 2 of 4 servers, and I don't want to have different formats. Does `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` help in this case to alter tables faster ? I never used it, is it risky, does it use less temp disk space ?

Comment: Another way I am thinking is to drop the index (not actual source column), alter the table, then add index again.

Comment: @adrianTNT - I added more.

Comment: The MySQL version is `8.0.30`, I ended up dropping the index, then creating it again, actually adding back index failed with `duplicate key NULL in some_field` for fields that were not defined as unique. Found some inconclusive bug reports about this. Maybe because I messed around with the primary index. Then I created a new table and moved all data. That finally worked.

Comment: `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` failed too when I tried it, it complained something about indexes, I cannot recall now. So that was not the way to do it :)

Comment: Alternatively I will try to save the text to NVME ssd as plain text and search it with `AG Silver Searcher`, I remmeber it is kind of fast (it uses all CPU threads) and I have ~ `64-128GB ram`, it might work better for me than the MySQL full text search :/